# R Shiny error : object 'plotFunction' of mode 'function' was not found

Tags: r, shiny

I want to create a function for that holds the downloadHandler function and feeds it its details dynamically but I keep getting the message

> "object 'plotFunction' of mode 'function' was not found"

My function for downloading is as follows:

```
downloadPlots <- function(fileName,plotFunction,fileFormat,fileContentType){
if(fileFormat=="pdf"){ #because it doesn't require specification of contentType. Others do
  downloadHandler(
    filename = fileName,
    content = function(file) {          
      pdf(file, pointsize = 12, bg = "white", res = NA)
      FUN <- match.fun(plotFunction) 
      FUN()
      dev.off()
    }
  )
}else{
  downloadHandler(
    filename = fileName,
    content = function(file) {
      if(fileFormat=="png")
        png(file, pointsize = 12, bg = "white", res = NA)
      FUN <- match.fun(plotFunction,descend = TRUE) 
      FUN()
      dev.off()
    },
    contentType = fileContentType
  )
}
```

}

This is how the function is called

```
output$histPng <- downloadPlots("histogram.png",histogram(),"png","image/png")
```

In the ui.R, the code for downloading the plot is as follows:

```
downloadButton('histPng','PNG')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem (without any testing) may be that you are passing your plot function to `downloadPlots()` incorrectly. Remove the parentheses from `histogram` in your function call:

```
output$histPng <- downloadPlots("histogram.png",histogram,"png","image/png")
```